# jQuery trigger click via $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I'm submitting data from pagex.php to pagey.php via jQuery post.

**pagex.php** contains

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = 'variable1';
        var y = 'variable2';
        $.post("/pagey.php", { var1: x, var2: y}, function(data) {});
    });
```

**pagey.php** contains

```
<form action=....>
<input type="text" name="x" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1'] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="y" value="<?php echo $_POST['var2'] ?>" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<script type="text/javascript">$('#submit').trigger('click')</script>
```

So basically when i post the values from pagex.php to pagey.php, i want to automatically submit the form on pagey.php . The jQuery line at the end of pagey.php will trigger an automatic click to the submit button. However jQuery is not triggering the submit click. it works if i access paygey.php directly (i tried it with pre defined variables) but not by doing $.post from pagex. I was assuming that by using `$.post` from pagex, pagey should automatically get the values and run the jQuery submit. What is the problem here.

Comment: use console to see the events and values being sent

Comment: @mls The post values are being sent properly. It's the click trigger that is not working. It only works if pagey is accessed directly via the browser.

Comment: then problem exists in button id

Comment: use correct id , find it on console, $("#correctid").live(trigger,function(e){}); should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript (which powers jQuery) is not run on the server, it's run from your users browser. So from my understanding, in order to run that little bit of script you will have to actually send your users to pagey.php

Comment: True, but you can get this code to run by pasting the returned document into the current one, thus running the javascript. But that might have other complications...

Comment: @JavaJosh94, so by what means can i automatically submit the form without accessing the page directly.

Comment: @Pinkie is pagey.php really necessary? Why don't you just post directly into pagey.php's form action url?

Comment: @Pinkie if your users are never going to see pagey.php, I don't see a point in it. Instead of passing the values to pagey.php you should pass them from pagex.php to the same page that you have pagey.php submit to.

Comment: i.e the url inside <form action="(THIS URL RIGHT HERE)"> is the one you should be posting your data to

Comment: pagey is submitting to itself. So the action url is pagey.php.

Comment: Since jQuery will not trigger via post, i'll have to send users directly to page. I will accept this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Weird stuff. I agree with JavaJosh94. Why on earth do you need pagey.php to post to itself? I mean what could pagey.php tell itself that it didn't know the first time before it posted to itself. (basically what JavaJosh94 is saying is "you're doing it wrong").

Answer (score 0):

```php
<input type="text" name="x" value="<?php echo $_POST[var1] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="y" value="<?php echo $_POST[var2] ?>" />
```

should be

```php
<input type="text" name="x" value="<?php echo $_POST['var1'] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="y" value="<?php echo $_POST['var2'] ?>" />
```

You need to fix your array indices.

Comment: yes i already have it like this. it was a typo in my question. I did mention it works if i access the pagey.php directly.

Comment: Does doing this work: `$.post("/pagey.php", { var1: 'variable1', var2: 'variable2'}, function(data) {});`?

Comment: This is the same line as my code as i have it. What has changed??

Answer (score 0):

you should post directly to the action url on pagey... what is the value of pagey if its a simple form that auto posts.

simple answer is to do a form post on document.ready in pagey...

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger question is why are you posting data to pagey if you just re-post it to another page using your form action?

Try posting the data directly to the action page and let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this will be useful to some of you. Regards.

```
<?php
    echo
    "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#submit').trigger('click');
        }); 
    </script>";
?>
```